# How is push method updating "chunked" array without accessing object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, declaration, variable-declaration

I understand the logic of the function below but i don't understand how the values are being added to the `chunked` array. The code returns `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]` by adding an element to `last` every iteration and "chunked" whenever the length of last is equal to `size`. However, nowhere does the code update the "chunked" array. i.e. `chunked.push(element)` or `chunked.push(last)`.

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked = [];
  const test = [];
  for (let element of array) {
    const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];

    console.log("This is last: " + last)
    
    if (!last || last.length === size) {
      chunked.push([element]);
    } else {
      last.push(element);
    }
  }
  console.log('test : ', test);
  return chunked;
}

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
```

Comment: `chunked` contains a reference to `last`, and it pushes onto `last`.

Comment: Thx i think i got it. I didnt realize in java script when setting two arrays to eachother changing one will change the other

Comment: It's not two arrays. It's two references to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration, `last` is undefined, so the condition

```
if (!last || last.length === size)`
```

is true. So it executes `chunked.push([element])`.

Then on the next iteration it does

```
const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];
```

This sets `last` to the `[element]` array that it previously pushed into the array. So when it then does `last.push(element)`, it adds to that array.

Then whenever the nested array fills up with `size` elements, the `if` condition will be true and it will push another nested array into `chunked`.

Comment: Thx i understand the logic bust as i mentioned i dont understand the mechanism that updates 'chunked' with a 'element' e.g. `last.push(element)` Doesnt this `last.push(element)` just add an `element` to `last`? It seems this should be `chunked.push(element)`

Comment: It's nested arrays. You push an element to the inner array, and push the inner array onto `chunked`

Comment: If you do `chunked.push(element)` you'll just get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, not `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`

Answer (score 0):

> All this snippet does is checks if the last element exists or is
> `chunked` array length is equal to the `size` then a new array is
> created with the current element else push the current element in the
> `last`.

It first gets the last element from the chunked. It will be always an array. when you have the last element then initially there are two conditions

1. you will get undefined: This will occur in the first iteration and only at the first time. If this is the case then a new array will be pushed in `chunked` as `chunked.push([element])`
2. You will get an array. Here also you will get 2 cases where:

- You will get an array of length equal to the `size` passed as an argument. Then in this case similar to case 1, we will push a new array with a single current element in it as `chunked.push([element])`.
- Your array length is less than or not equal to the size then we push the element in the array as `last.push(element);`

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned i understand the logic. I dont understand the mechanism that updates `chunked` with a new `element`. Its probably a java script specific thing i dont understand